# Filter a ComboBox inside a ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, filtering

I have a mapping table represented by a ListView:

```
<ListView Name="PaycodeMapping_ListView" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Model.PaycodeMappings, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        
                            <!-- Company Code -->
                            <ComboBox Name="CompanyCode_ComboBox"
                                      Width="100"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Margin="0"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CompanyList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Company, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

                            <!-- Paycode ComboBox -->
                            <ComboBox Name="Paycode_ComboBox"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      Width="125"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Paycodes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="CodeDesc"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Paycode, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
```

The object `Paycodes` is a collection of objects which each contain a `CompanyCode`, `PayrollCode`, and `CodeDesc`. For instance:

| CompanyCode | PayrollCode | CodeDesc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | VACA | Vacation |
| 001 | 1000 | Regular Pay |
| 001 | 1010 | Overtime |
| 002 | 2000 | Vacation |
| 002 | 2001 | Shift Pay |
| 002 | 3000 | Hourly Overtime |

I would like to filter the list of `Paycodes` presented in the `Paycode_ComboBox` based on the `SelectedItem` in `CompanyCode_ComboBox`. So if company 001 is select only Vacation, Regular Pay, and Overtime would be available in `Paycode_ComboBox`.

My issue is how to filter each individual ListViewItem `Paycode_ComboBox`.

Comment: could you post somewhere (github) a functional sample? it will be easier to test with your code.  and are you using MVVM?

Comment: another question could you show your models -> Model.PaycodeMappings...?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a CollectionViewSource.

Without more information on your models, I can't make a more specific example, but consider the following:

ViewModel (uses CommunityToolkit.MVVM)

```cs
public class DemoViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    public IEnumerable<string> Cities {get;} = new List<string>
    {
        "Atlanta",
        "Buffalo",
        "Austin",
        "Anchorage",
        "Columbus",
        "Cincinnati",
    };

    public IEnumerable<char> Letters { get; } = new List<char>
    {
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
    };

    private char _selectedLetter = 'A';
    public char SelectedLetter
    {
        get => _selectedLetter;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedLetter, value);
    }
}
```

Window:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:DemoViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="citiesView" Source="{Binding Cities}"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name ="LetterSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Letters}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLetter}" SelectionChanged="LetterSelector_SelectionChanged"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource citiesView}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ((CollectionViewSource)Resources["citiesView"]).View.Filter = item => ((string)item).StartsWith(((DemoViewModel)DataContext).SelectedLetter);
    }

    private void LetterSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CollectionViewSource)Resources["citiesView"]).View.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create the CollectionViewSource as a property in the view model and bind the combobox to it to eliminate code behind, but this is a Windows specific API, so if you prefer to keep your ViewModels platform agnostic, that won't be ideal.

```cs
public class DemoViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public DemoViewModel()
    {
        Cities.Filter = item => ((string)item).StartsWith(SelectedLetter);
    }

    public ICollectionView Cities {get;} = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new List<string>
    {
        "Atlanta",
        "Buffalo",
        "Austin",
        "Anchorage",
        "Columbus",
        "Cincinnati",
    });

    public IEnumerable<char> Letters { get; } = new List<char>
    {
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
    };

    private char _selectedLetter = 'A';
    public char SelectedLetter
    {
        get => _selectedLetter;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _selectedLetter, value))
            {
                Cities.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:DemoViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Letters}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLetter}"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

You can also use an ObservableCollection instead of the List if needed.

Comment: My issue is how do I bind it to the `CompanyCode_ComboBox SelectedItem`. I have done this when there is just one ComboBox and its value is a parameter in the ViewModel that I can access. How would I reference the `CompanyCode_ComboBox` of a particular line in the ListView?

Comment: @BrianKE I've added a more comprehensive example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is how to filter each individual ListViewItem Paycode_ComboBox.

You should bind to a filtered collection of paycodes to begin with.

The MVVM way of solving this would be to add an `IEnumerable<Paycode>` property to the type that represents an item in the `ListView` and populate this one in the setter of the `Company` property that gets set when you select a company in the other `ComboBox`.

So don't bind the second `ComboBox` to the `CompanyList` property of the view model. Bind it to a property of the item class:

```
<ComboBox Name="Paycode_ComboBox"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Width="125"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Paycodes}"
    DisplayMemberPath="CodeDesc"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Paycode, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
```